# Migrating a Database into Akka Persistence

Tags: java, database, scala, akka

There isn't much documentation on best practices for Akka Persistence.

Like the rest of the world I am in a relational database (postgres), but would like to at least partially move over to using akka persistence. This seems like a pretty regular use case for people.  What's best practices?

Let's say I have a User class in a RDB, the `persons` table.  Instinctively, I would think that you should do a DB lookup when the to-be-persisted actor is initialized, but that doesn't work because if the actor has been previously created, then it hasn't replayed it's journal yet. I could do something with a flag, after it runs it's Recovering, but I'm not sure the best place to hook that in either.

How do I make a function that is called only once when a persisted Akka actor is originally created?

Comment: One way is to create the actor and then feed all DB entries as domain events to it (e.g. send CreateUser messages) on the first instantiation of the system (preferably creating snapshots in-between). Then the events are in the journal and will be picked up upon next start.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but on production systems who is to say that you can do such a direct migration like this?  If you have millions of users you don't want to shut off your app, migrate, and then start it back up again.  A lazy loading process is probably in order.